# Custom theme options Radio inputs not saving

Tags: options, settings-api

Why isn't the following option getting saved? Have been searching for quite some time and can't get it to work.

Settings code:

```
add_settings_section( 'aa_myoption_section', null, null, 'mypage-options' );

add_settings_field(
   'aa_myoption',
   null,
   'aa_myoption_interface',
   'mypage-options',
   'aa_myoption_section',
);
register_setting ( 'myoptions_group', 'aa_myoption' );
```

aa_myoption_interface function:

```
$options = get_option( 'aa_myoption' );
echo 'debug: ' . $options;

<input id="first_radio" type="radio" name="radio_group" value="first" <?php checked( $options, 'first', true ); ?>>
<label for="first_radio">First Radio</label>
<input id="second_radio" type="radio" name="radio_group" value="second" <?php checked( $options, 'second', true ); ?>>
<label for="second_radio">Second Radio</label>
<input id="third_radio" type="radio" name="radio_group" value="third" <?php checked( $options, 'third', true ); ?>>
<label for="third_radio">Third Radio</label>
```

In addition to that I would like to know how is it possible to store an array in `aa_myoption` and save multiple fields like `get_option('aa_myoption')['first_field'], get_option('aa_myoption')['second_field']` and so on. I tried saving text input like this and I got an error saying "Warning: 'first_field' illegal string'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The option isn't getting saved because the input name has to be `aa_myoption` (matches the 2nd parameter for `register_setting()`) or in the array notation like `aa_myoption[my_field]`.

Comment: I get the following error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'my_field'.
I use it like this:
<?php $options = get_option( 'aa_myoption' ); ?>
<input id="field-id" type="radio" name="aa_myoption[my_field]" value="myvalue" <?php checked( $options['my_field'], 'myvalue', true ); ?>>

Comment: I fixed the error by doing this (don't know if this is the right way - is it?): 
<?php $options = get_option( 'aa_myoption' ); $the_option = $options['my_field']; ?> <input id="field-id" type="radio" name="aa_myoption[my_field]" value="myvalue" <?php checked( $the_option, 'myvalue', true ); ?>> however settings are still not saved.

Comment: Seems weird but it worked after turning this --> <?php $options = get_option('aa_myoption'); $the_option = $options['my_field']; ?> into this --> <?php $options = get_option('aa_myoption')['my_field']; ?> Could you explain to me why is this happening? I left my previous comments so you can see the process. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It could be because you already saved the option, so `$options` has the `my_field` item. Anyway, I hope the answer helps? :)

Comment: $options has never had a value before, I checked inside my database. Anyway, I will look further into it, the fact that works does half the job for me personally, the point is to know how and why :) Thank you very very much, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't the following option getting saved?

Because the database option name (the *second* parameter for [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/)) is `aa_myoption`, hence the input `name` has to be `aa_myoption` or in the array notation like `aa_myoption[my_field]`:

```html
<input name="aa_myoption">           <!-- like this -->
<input name="aa_myoption[my_field]"> <!-- or this -->
```

Secondly, when you retrieve the option value and when it is an array of settings (like the second `<input>` above), and *as with any other arrays, you should check if an array key exists before attempting to use the value*:

```php
<?php
$options = (array) get_option( 'aa_myoption', array() );
$my_field = isset( $options['my_field'] ) ? $options['my_field'] : '';

// Then for example when using checked():
?>
<input name="aa_myoption[my_field]" type="checkbox" value="myvalue"<?php checked( $my_field, 'myvalue' ); ?>>
<?php
// Or you can also use wp_parse_args() to make sure all KEYS are set:
$options = wp_parse_args( get_option( 'aa_myoption', array() ), array(
    'my_field' => '',
) );

// Then for example when using checked():
?>
<input name="aa_myoption[my_field]" type="checkbox" value="myvalue"<?php checked( $options['my_field'], 'myvalue' ); ?>>
```

### Additional notes

1. `$my_field = isset( $options['my_field'] ) ? $options['my_field'] : '';`

   The empty string doesn't necessarily need to be empty, we're simply assigning a *default value* to `$my_field` when the array key/item `my_field` doesn't already exist, and you can even use the PHP 7 format — `$my_field = $options['my_field'] ?? '';` which does the same thing as the one above. =)
2. `$options = (array) get_option( 'aa_myoption', array() );`

   A bit of explanation:

   - I'm telling [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) to return an empty array if the option does not exist yet, i.e. the database query `WHERE option_name = 'aa_myoption'` returned no results.
   - I'm type-casting the value to an array to make sure it's indeed an array, because WordPress options (both custom and core options like `admin_email`) can be easily filtered by plugins and your own code.. e.g. via the [`option_<option name>` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/), and it *is* possible that a plugin (or custom code) returned a non-array value.

     But of course, the best practice is for filter callbacks to always return the proper type of value.

     And I removed the sample test cases from this answer, but you can always check them [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/363621/revisions). ;)

     Also, I'd likely use the [`wp_parse_args()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_args/), but I'd probably create a `my_theme_get_options()` function or something like that, which returns an array with options from the database and merged with the default values. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, passing an empty array as a default value never crossed my mind, this is really nice however I do not get why type casting is needed since the default value is indeed an array. Isn't PHP a "loose" language? I mean, I would totally understand if we were talking about C. Is it because the option may exist before? In addition, I have problem understanding why passing an empty string in $my_field (inside the array previously declared).

Comment: Does the "Update" part help, or am I misunderstanding you? :)

Comment: You helped me a lot Sally but I still do not get why type casting is needed however I wouldn't like to bother you any more. :)

Comment: I revised the answer again, but just the additional note #2. I hope that's OK & all the best. :)

Comment: It is great! Thanks a ton, you are awesome!!

Comment: Related: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/#comment-3230